# External extensions don't work when archive

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, archive

I have some files in my project dedicated to extension for Colors, string and images like this

```
extension Color{
     static var mimotoPrimary: Color{
         Color("mimoto_primary")
     }

     static var mimotoPrimaryLight: Color{
         Color("mimoto_primary_light")
     }

     static var mimotoWhiteDark: Color{
         Color("white_dark")
     }

      ...
}
```

It's pretty simple.
This extensions works perfectly when building and running.
However when I try to archive this errors appear
[image]

None of the extensions I have works.

I have set the schemes to be the same when Running than when archiving and even doing that running goes well and archiving goes wrong.

I'm using XCode 13.1

Any idea?

Comment: This may or mayn't help, but deleting your derived data and cleaning the build folder may correct the issue. If not, do it again and restart.

Comment: can you post code of class Color?

Comment: @ВладимирКовальчук Color is native SwiftUI view

Comment: sorry, didn't see the tag swiftui

Comment: Thank you guys but I have already solved the problem. It was due to the project structure somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error resided in the project folder structure. This is how I had my project sructure:
[image]

It turns out that for some reason those files are not detected in that folder, instead, they needed to be in any other folder. This worked:

[image]

However I don't the reason of this issue, the first project structure worked well when building and running.

Comment: Seems to fix it for me too. Have any idea why this is the case?

Comment: No clue at all.